# Split sentence into words but having trouble with the punctuations in C#

Tags: c#, regex, split, words, sentence

I have seen a few similar questions but I am trying to achieve this.

Given a string, str="The moon is our natural satellite, i.e. it rotates around the Earth!"
I want to extract the words and store them in an array. 
The expected array elements would be this.

```
the 
moon 
is 
our 
natural 
satellite 
i.e. 
it  
rotates 
around 
the 
earth
```

I tried using String.split( ','\t','\r') but this does not work correctly. I also tried removing the ., and other punctuation marks but I would want a string like "i.e." to be parsed out too. What is the best way to achieve this? 
I also tried using regex.split to no avail.

```
string[] words = Regex.Split(line, @"\W+");
```

Would surely appreciate some nudges in the right direction.

Comment: The second `.` in `i.e.` and a punctuation `.` are indistinguishable unless you add a list of words that are known to end in `.`.

Comment: I note that the moon *rotates* around its own axis. It *revolves* around the earth.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A regex solution.

```
(\b[^\s]+\b)
```

And if you *really* want to fix that last `.` on `i.e.` you could use this.

```
((\b[^\s]+\b)((?<=\.\w).)?)
```

Here's the code I'm using.

```
  var input = "The moon is our natural satellite, i.e. it rotates around the Earth!";
  var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"((\b[^\s]+\b)((?<=\.\w).)?)");

  foreach(var match in matches)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(match);
  }
```

Results:

> ```
> The
> moon
> is
> our
> natural
> satellite
> i.e.
> it
> rotates
> around
> the
> Earth
> ```

Comment: But isn't that going to include punctuation as part of the word? So in the example above the last word would be "Earth!" ...

Comment: No it won't match the punctuation in earth. `\b` matches on word boundaries.

Comment: @Thecodeking, What about matching "i.e."? or something like "u.n.i.c.e.f"?

Comment: Comes out as `u.n.i.c.e.f` or `i.e` :)

Comment: How about "can't"? Won't that come out as "can" and "t"?

Comment: And are you using this with Regex.Split?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Ill mark this as the answer. I will use my existing string split method but will keep this as an option. Clearly, I need to learn more about reg exps.

Comment: Six years later it's still beautiful :)

Answer (score 9):

I suspect the solution you're looking for is much more complex than you think.  You're looking for some form of actual language analysis, or at a minimum a dictionary, so that you can determine whether a period is part of a word or ends a sentence.  Have you considered the fact that it may do both?

Consider adding a dictionary of allowed "words that contain punctuation."  This may be the simplest way to solve your problem.

Comment: Regex does this with `\b` so you don't have to, admittedly there are some grey areas. For instance `i.e.` with match as `i.e`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
var str="The moon is our natural satellite, i.e. it rotates around the Earth!";
var a = str.Split(new char[] {' ', '\t'});
for (int i=0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" -{0}", a[i]);
}
```

Results:

```
 -The
 -moon
 -is
 -our
 -natural
 -satellite,
 -i.e.
 -it
 -rotates
 -around
 -the
 -Earth!
```

you could do some post-processing of the results, removing commas and semicolons, etc.

Comment: Would this be the best solution. Would post processing be considered inefficient for cases like these?

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Matches(input, @"\b\w+\b").OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value)
```