# c# line by line reading txt file

Tags: c#, arrays, file, txtextcontrol

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //dosya seçiniz click
    {
        //OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        //file.Filter = "Txt Dosyası |*.txt";
        //file.ShowDialog();

        string[] veri = new string[1000];
        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Murat\Pictures\New folder\DE.TXT");
        string satir;

        while (SR.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            satir = SR.ReadLine();
            veri[0] = satir;
            richTextBox1.AppendText(satir + "\n");

            richTextBox2.AppendText("{" + '"' + satir + '"' + ", new DataElement { Tag ='" + '"' + veri[0] + '"' + ", Type = FieldTypes.");
            satir = SR.ReadLine();
            richTextBox2.AppendText(satir + ", ");
            satir = SR.ReadLine();
            if (satir.Length > 3)
            {
                richTextBox2.AppendText("MinLength = 0,");
            }
```

hello, this my code partition, 
I am reading the data from line by line txt file. But how do I make array this words?

There is a Txt File. There are line-words in it.
I will assign the words in this line to the array, and I will process them. But I could not create an array. And that's why I've been using the new line for many times.

Comment: Aren't you calling `ReadLine()` a bit too often?

Comment: but, because I read line by line but could not line it up.

Comment: What words? How can you tell when the data ends?

Comment: please connect teamviewer, basic problem :S

Comment: @MuratÇetiner You question is un-clear. Please take some time to re-write it and explain your needs better.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten 
There is a Txt File. There are line-words in it.
I will assign the words in this line to the array, and I will process them. But I could not create an array. And that's why I've been using the new line for many times.

Comment: So, I think that Michael has the right answer for you.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten you dont understand me.

Comment: @MuratÇetiner That's exactly why i asked you to take some time and edit this post to better explain the problem you are facing

Comment: Please show an example of how the file looks like and what result you are expecting. You are putting all the results into the first array position `veri[0];`

Answer (score 2):

What about a single `.ReadAllLines()`?

EDIT:
You might use [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx). You pass the path of the file to read and you'll get a string-array as result. Each array element represents one line of text in the file.

But you can also continue using the `StreamReader`. Then you could use [StreamReader.ReadToEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend(v=vs.110).aspx). This will return a single string that contains the hole content of the text file. Then you have two choices: First you can split by `CRLF` to get the lines and process them as you want. Or you'll start digging into regular expressions and read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311734/split-sentence-into-words-but-having-trouble-with-the-punctuations-in-c-sharp) and others about regular expressions and splitting/extracting words...

Comment: I would suggest you to add a bit more description to the post. The OP uses `StreamReader` Which doesn't have `ReadAllLines` and he might not know where to find it and how to use it

Answer (score 1):

You should consider rewriting your "readingfunction".

use the following method as startingpoint:

```
public List<string> readWordsFromFile(string file) {
    list<string> result = new List<string>();
    using(Streamreader sr = new Streamreader(file)) {
        while(!sr.EndOfFile) { // making sure to read the whole file
            result.Append(sr.ReadLine().Split(" ")); // splitting words by " " (space)
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

you also could do `ReadToEnd().Split(" ")`

Comment: I want to sing the individual words. Not that.